# bash not finding executables on Catalina: why & how to fix?

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, catalina

As I was typing the title, I saw a suggestion that this might be a duplicate of.  But the suggestion vanished before I could click on it.

'sh' is actually bash

```
sh: sleep: command not found
sh: dirname: command not found
sh: dirname: command not found
sh: sleep: command not found
sh: dirname: command not found
^C
sh-3.2# echo $path
/usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
sh-3.2# echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
sh-3.2# which dirname
/usr/bin/dirname
sh-3.2# which sleep
/bin/sleep
# the command that got those error messages was:
sh-3.2# grep -v copy /tmp/tmp | while read PATH; do dirname "$(dirname "$PATH")"; sleep 1; done
```

All available updates installed. 10.15.2

Comment: try using full paths to the commands instead of the mini versions (like `/bin/sleep 1`) https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/101170/why-do-i-need-to-put-sh-before-running-sh-files/101180#101180 Also see the sidebar https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/170464/why-am-i-getting-command-not-found-even-though-path-to-command-exists-in-path-va?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the full path works, but it should not be needed.  And since that works, it is not caused by permissions as in the cited item.  Another difference is that this failure occurs whether root or low-privilege.  And has been an issue since Catalina arrived.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/264990/trying-to-install-a-sh-that-will-automate-installation-of-pkg https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/101171/313842 ignore the second link of first comment, mistake there. Also, I never voted to close as duplicates, just adding for information. Your tone sounds defensive

Comment: You're using `PATH` as a regular variable (`while read PATH`), which messes up the system's ability to find command executables (same as [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13181858/rsync-in-shell-for-loop)). There are a bunch of all-caps variable names with special meanings, and accidentally using one of them for something else can cause trouble; this is why you should use lower- or mixed-case variable names unless you want that special meaning.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `grep ... sleep 1; done` command?

Comment: @GordonDavisson, if that isn’t an embarrassing screw-up for a software engineer to make!  Make that a checkable answer.  (Although I have had a lot of command not found for which that is not the answer, and they all started with Catalina.  But this is certainly the Answer to this one.)

Comment: @klanomath the sleep was to slow down the output so I could look at it.  Once I saw that it did what I wanted, I took out the sleep and redirected to a file.

Comment: @WGroleau I meant the whole command (but was too lazy to write it) - especially: what's the content of /tmp/tmp?

Comment: Was an extremely long file listing the full path to every MP3 on the system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to use of the special variable `PATH` (in `while read PATH`). `PATH` is used by they system as a list of directories to find command executables; if it doesn't point to the usual binaries directories, the OS won't be able to find commands any more.

Solution: use a different (preferably lower- or mixed-case) name for the variable.

There are quite a few all-caps variable names with some sort of special meaning to the shell, operating system, or various commands themselves. To avoid stumbling into conflicts and unintended consequences like this, it's generally best to avoid all-caps variable names in shell scripts (unless you want the special meaning). In fact, according to the [POSIX standard for environment variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html):

> The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase
>   letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any
>   environment variables with names from this name space without
>   modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.

Comment: Thanks.  Rather embarrassing error to make.  Not noticing is even more embarrassing.  Note that $path is an exception to the quote, though.